# Why does Spring annotations and xml configurations inject collections differently?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say there's some service which stores data in collection

```
public class BookingService{
    private Set<Record> bookingDB;

    public BookingService(Set<Record> bookingDB){
        this.bookingDB = bookingDB;
    }
}
```

Now, if bookingDB is injected via XML configuration

```
<bean id="bookingService" class="com.example.BookingService">
    <constructor-arg><set></set></constructor-arg>        
</bean>
```

Spring will construct class with empty set of Records as expected

but if the same is done through annotations then Spring will construct Set for bookingDB which already contains one Record generated by Record's default constructor

```
@Autowired
public BookingService( Set<Record> bookingDB ) {
    this.bookingDB = bookingDB;
    System.out.println(this.bookingDB.size());
}
```

returns 1

Why would Spring do that? Even if I explicitly tell it to return empty HashMap in bean definition, Autowire constructor will get Set with 1 record.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "bookingDB")
    public Set<Record> bookingDB(){
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

The only way I found is to inject value directly but that misses the point of passing DB through constructor:

```
@Component
public class BookingService{
    @Resource(name = "bookingDB")
    private Set<Record> bookingDB;
```

Comment: Set<Ticket> bookingDB or Set<Record> bookingDB?? which one is correct?

Comment: Let me guess your `Record` (or `Ticket` which ever is right) is also marked with `@Component`? And no the XML and Java versions aren't the same, so yes they yield different results.

Comment: @clevertension Sorry, that's just a typo in example code. `Ticket` should be `Record`.
@M. Deinum yes, `Record` is `@Component` - does it mean that injecting through properties is the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually about injecting when you define bean and then also define collection via this bean when spring application context is initialized bean will be injected into collection

checkout https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/injecting-collections.html

Comment: Marking as correct answer, although it only 90% complete. **_Basically_**: Passing `Collection<bean_type>` as constructor argument using annotations has two sides to it: **Pros**: Spring will automatically collect ALL initialized beans of that type and pass them to constructor. **Cons**: Spring will automatically collect **ALL** initialized beans of that type and pass them to constructor. And if there are no beans in the context yet at least one instance will be build using default constructor